# Interact with SharePoint Web Part Programmatically from JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, ribbon

My colleague is attempting to write a SharePoint add-in that interacts with a web part in SharePoint. Specifically the project schedule add-in.

We have all of the basic business logic implemented, but we want to paste some data in a field. Currently the best we have is a button that copies this to the user's clipboard, but we would prefer to programmatically add this data to a field in the web-part.

We have been able to hack the DOM to add the data, but of course this is not persisted correctly.

My question is whether or not SharePoint has an api for intracting with web-parts. I have seen other ribbon buttons change things in web-parts, but not third-party add-ins.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.